# Is there a way how to reverse code for adding new line

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below which, in a simple request form, gives requestor an option to add a line for the same user.

When "Yes" is selected from a drop-down menu, a new line populates with the same Name and Alias used in the previous row, while other rows below it would move down by one row accordingly.

The code to ADD a new line (works fine) is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AWS Applications")

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F7:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row).Copy .Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":C" & Target.Row + 1)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

I modified the above code as follows so it does remove a row below if the "No" option is selected. And it is working properly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AWS Applications")

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F7:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row).Copy .Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":C" & Target.Row + 1)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F7:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "No" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If


End With

End Sub
```

However, I want to make sure that a below row is deleted after selecting "No" only in cases where the below row that is to be deleted contains same data as the row above. As it is now, it removes the below line in any case, i.e. even if the requestor previously didn't click "Yes", and that's not a desired outcome.

I've been trying to modify the "No" condition as follows but still struggling:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F7:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "No" Then
        If Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row).Value = Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":C" & Target.Row + 1).Value Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
End If
```

Could you please help?

FOLLOW-UP:
The code I'm having now is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AWS Applications")

LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F7:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        .Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row).Copy .Range("A" & 
Target.Row + 1 & ":C" & Target.Row + 1)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If



If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F7:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "No" Then

    AllOk = True
    For Each xCel In UpperRow.Cells
        If AllOk And (xCel.Value <> xCel.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
            AllOk = False
        End If
    Next xCel
    If AllOk Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End If

End With
End Sub
```

I keep getting '424' error "Object required" and the debug highlights this: `For Each xCel In UpperRow.Cells`

Could you please help? Apologies I'm a beginner in this...

Comment: hi. i think u cant get a value from a multicell range. try to do a compare cell by cell.

Comment: Where you check if the answer is Yes or No?

Comment: SJR: in a dedicated column called "New Line for the Same User", please see the screenshot
https://i.imgur.com/Se0lZ9F.png

Comment: Both `Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row).Value` and `Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":C" & Target.Row + 1).Value` return multi dimensional arrays (add them as a watch and check the output). You can't do a direct comparison between the 2. You have to loop through the values

Comment: Thanks, Zac! Could you advise how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

As an indicative answer

```
AllOk = True
for each xCel in UpperRow.Cells
   if AllOk and (xCel.Value <> xCel.Offset(1,0).Value) then
      AllOk = False
   End If
Next xCel
IF AllOk then
   ' Delete the Row
End If
```

You'll need to fill in some details and maybe some error checking - not a full answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm a beginner in this and even though I've tried to add this piece to my code and modify it, I keep getting '424' error "Object required" and the debug highlights this:

`For Each xCel In UpperRow.Cells`

Comment: UpperRow is just a generic (but meaningful) name - not literally a variable name